# I am getting a nullpointer exception

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

Spinner spinner;
String values[];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll()
            .penaltyLog()
            .penaltyDialog()
            .build());

    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll()
            .penaltyLog()
            .build());

    TextView wid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wid);
    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.url);

    JSONObject json = null;
    String str = "";
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://egcrm.cloudapp.net/operations/index.php/dcapi/gettrucktypes");
    //http://demos.tricksofit.com/files/json.php

    try {
        response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
        str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
        for (int i=0; i < jArray.length();i++){
        json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        wid.setText(json.getString("Key"));
        name.setText(json.getString("Value"));
        // url.setText(json.getString("url"));
            String shiva=new String();
            shiva=json.getString("Value");
            values=new String[jArray.length()];
            values[i]=shiva;
    }

    }

    catch ( JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,values);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(aa);
    }

}
```

logcat:

> 01-26 11:56:12.799 19322-19322/com.example.sai.lasttry
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.example.sai.lasttry, PID: 19322
>                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                    at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:197)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:507)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1083)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Comment: Please paste the console output

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: add  values=new String[jArray.length()]; above for loop

Answer (score 0):

Root cause : new String[] in loop

```
values=new String[jArray.length()];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in this line

```
str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```

It seems you are trying to get the data not to post, so do like this

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://egcrm.cloudapp.net/operations/index.php/dcapi/gettrucktypes");
HttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient()
                    .execute(httpGet);
```

Then after get string like

```
String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(),
                "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is because of theses lines:

```
values=new String[jArray.length()];
values[i]=shiva;
```

and it is because values array is not filling up, and it gives `NullPointerException`.
try to debug and check what is coming in `jArray.length()` and make sure it is filling up your values array.